Android Room start transaction from repository
I'm currently developing an Android app in Kotlin using Room for data storage.
In my repository class, I listen to changes to the database using Flows obtained from my dao and then verify, convert and publish the data to the rest of my app also using Flows.
However, I have some complex operations on the data that require more than one write to the database. If I just use the normal methods of the dao, Room may send partially updated data to the Flow, which may lead to crashes or wrong data in the UI. So I figured out that I needed to use a transaction to prevent that issue, but I could find only two ways to start a transaction:

The withTransaction() method of the RoomDatabase class, which would require me to pass that class as a dependency to my repository
The @Transaction annotation, which would require me to move some of my logic into the dao

Both options are not optimal, so I came up with the following method in my dao:
@Transaction
open suspend fun transaction(transaction: suspend () -> Unit): Unit = transaction()

It just takes a lambda and executes it in a transaction, which allows me to manage transactions from my repository using the following pattern:
dao.transaction {
  // Multiple database writes
}

Since my experience with Room and Kotlin is very limited, I just wanted to ask whether there are any drawbacks or better ways to solve this. Thanks.
